# php directory explorer script help

Tags: php, directory

I have created this php script which displays the contents of a designated directory and allows users to download each file. Here is the code:

```
<?php  
if ($handle = opendir('test')) {  
     while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {  
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {  
            echo "<a href='test/$file'>$file\n</a><br/>";  
        }  
    }  
    closedir($handle);  
}
?>
```

This script also displays folders, but when I click a folder, it does display the contents of the folder, but in the default Apache autoindex view.

What I would like the script to do when a folder is clicked, is display the contents, but in the same fashion as the original script does (as this is more editable with css and the like).
Would you know how to achieve this?

Comment: I couldn't vote up until recently, but you're right, I should vote up and "tick" the answers I am given, now that I can. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a link to the directory itself, but to a php page which displays the contents.

Change your php code to somthing like:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['dir'])) {
    $current_dir = $_REQUEST['dir'];
} else {
    $current_dir = 'test';
}

if ($handle = opendir($current_dir)) {
     while (false !== ($file_or_dir = readdir($handle))) {
        if(in_array($file_or_dir, array('.', '..'))) continue;
        $path = $current_dir.'/'.$file_or_dir;
        if(is_file($path)) {
            echo '<a href="/Implementation/'.$path.'">'.$file_or_dir."\n</a><br/>";
        } else {
            echo '<a href="script.php?dir='.$path.'">'.$file_or_dir."\n</a><br/>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

PS write you html code with double quotes.

Comment: The code I suggested IS dynamic. It creates a link to your php script (script.php) with a variable called dir (?dir=test/$file). The dir variable is then used to display the contents of it.

Comment: Going into one folder works perfectly :D, but if I click onto another folder, this error is displayed: "Warning: opendir(test/Folder Two) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Implementation\testFolderiFrame.php on line 8" :( As well, clicking on any file displays this message: "Warning: opendir(test/clock.html) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No error in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Implementation\testFolderiFrame.php on line 8" Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: For the folder click: are you 100% sure the directory exists? For the file click the script tries to use the file as a directory. What do you want to happen when the user clicks the file?

Comment: Yes, the folder definitely exists, I even created a new folder, and the same error occurred when I clicked it. And for a file click, I would like the script to download/view the file when it is clicked, like my original script did. :)

Comment: I've updated the code. It should be working the way you want it now. have fun with it. Don't forget the check as answer if it works.

Comment: Well, now the folder navigation works perfectly (I've tested four levels of folders :D) However, the file click, which should download the file, is not working. When I click a file, it returns the error: "Object not found!". The url that has been constructed is "http://localhost/test/clock.html" but it should be "http://localhost/Implementation/test/clock.html". Would it help if I told you that the php script file is outside the folder it is displaying. In other words, the php script is in "localhost/Implementation" and the folder the script is displaying is "localhost/Implementation/test".

Comment: I've added the implementation folder to link. Check it out.

Comment: Brilliant! It all works flawlessly now. Thank you very much for all your help :D On a small side note, would you happen to know how to configure the script to display a directory from outside the server root, like to G:/test ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need your HREF to point back to your PHP script, and not the directory. You will then need to update your PHP script to now which directory it needs to read.